# Store static files on S3 but staticfiles.json manifest locally

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, deployment, django-storage

I have a Django application running on Heroku. To store and serve my static files, I'm using [django-storages](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages) with my S3 bucket, as well as the standard Django `ManifestFilesMixin`. I'm also using [django-pipeline](https://github.com/jazzband/django-pipeline).

In code:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import ManifestFilesMixin
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage
from pipeline.storage import PipelineMixin

class S3PipelineManifestStorage(PipelineMixin, ManifestFilesMixin, S3BotoStorage):
    pass
```

The setup works, however the `staticfiles.json` manifest is *also* stored on S3. I can see two problems with that:

1. My app's storage instance would have to fetch `staticfiles.json` from S3, instead of just getting it from the local file system. This makes little sense performance-wise. The only consumer of the manifest file is the server app itself, so it might as well be stored on the local file system instead of remotely.

   I'm not sure how significant this issue is since I suppose (or hope) that the server app caches the file after reading it once.
2. The manifest file is written *during* deployment by `collectstatic`, so if any already-running instances of the previous version of the server application read the manifest file from S3 before the deployment finishes and the new slug takes over, they could fetch the wrong static files - ones which should only be served for instances of the new slug.

   Note that specifically on Heroku, it's possible for new app instances to pop up dynamically, so even if the app does cache the manifest file, it's possible its first fetch of it would be during the deployment of the new slug.

   This scenario as described is specific to Heroku, but I guess there would be similar issues with other environments.

The obvious solution would be to store the manifest file on the local file system. Each slug would have its own manifest file, performance would be optimal, and there won't be any deployment races as described above.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 9):

Some time ago I read [this article](https://devblog.kogan.com/blog/a-hidden-gem-in-django-1-7-manifeststaticfilesstorage) which I believe fits your case well.
In there at the last paragraph exists the following:

> **Where is staticfiles.json located?**
>
> By default `staticfiles.json` will reside in `STATIC_ROOT` which is the
>   directory where all static files are collected in. 
>   **We host all our static assets on an S3 bucket which means `staticfiles.json` by default would end up being synced to S3. However, we wanted it to live in the code directory so we could package it and ship it to each app server.**
>
> As a result of this, `ManifestStaticFilesStorage` will look for
>   `staticfiles.json` in `STATIC_ROOT` in order to read the mappings. We had
>   to overwrite this behaviour, so we subclassed `ManifestStaticFilesStorage`:
>
> ```
> from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import
> ManifestStaticFilesStorage from django.conf import settings
>
> class KoganManifestStaticFilesStorage(ManifestStaticFilesStorage):
>
>     def read_manifest(self):
>         """
>         Looks up staticfiles.json in Project directory
>         """
>         manifest_location = os.path.abspath(
>             os.path.join(settings.PROJECT_ROOT, self.manifest_name)
>         )
>         try:
>             with open(manifest_location) as manifest:
>                 return manifest.read().decode('utf-8')
>         except IOError:
>             return None
> ```
>
> With the above change, Django static template tag will now read the
>   mappings from `staticfiles.json` that resides in project root directory.

*Haven't used it myself, so let me know if it helps!*

Comment: This is helpful, though probably incomplete as someone mentions in the comments in the link you posted - `save_manifest` probably needs to be overridden as well.

Comment: Good to know @Darna!

Answer (score 6):

The answer of @John and [Kogan](https://devblog.kogan.com/blog/a-hidden-gem-in-django-1-7-manifeststaticfilesstorage) is great but doesn't give the full code needed to make this work: As @Danra mentioned you need to also save the `staticfiles.json` in the source folder to make this work. Here's the code I've created based on the above answer:

```
import json
import os
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

from whitenoise.storage import CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage
# or if you don't use WhiteNoiseMiddlware:
# from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import ManifestStaticFilesStorage


class LocalManifestStaticFilesStorage(CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage):
    """
    Saves and looks up staticfiles.json in Project directory
    """
    manifest_location = os.path.abspath(settings.BASE_DIR)  # or settings.PROJECT_ROOT depending on how you've set it up in your settings file.
    manifest_storage = FileSystemStorage(location=manifest_location)

    def read_manifest(self):

        try:
            with self.manifest_storage.open(self.manifest_name) as manifest:
                return manifest.read().decode('utf-8')
        except IOError:
            return None

    def save_manifest(self):
        payload = {'paths': self.hashed_files, 'version': self.manifest_version}
        if self.manifest_storage.exists(self.manifest_name):
            self.manifest_storage.delete(self.manifest_name)
        contents = json.dumps(payload).encode('utf-8')
        self.manifest_storage._save(self.manifest_name, ContentFile(contents))
```

Now you can use `LocalManifestStaticFilesStorage` for your `STATICFILES_STORAGE`. When running `manage.py collectstatic`, your manifest will be saved to your root project folder and Django will look for it there when serving the content.

If you have a deployment with multiple virtual machines, make sure to run `collectstatic` only once and copy the `staticfiles.json` file to all the machines in your deployment as part of your code deployment. The nice thing about this is that even if some machines don't have the latest update yet, they will still be serving the correct content (corresponding to the current version of the code), so you can perform a gradual deploy where there is a mixed state.

Comment: using django-storages with the `ManifestFilesMixin` via a custom storage class `StaticStorage(ManifestFilesMixin, S3Boto3Storage)`.  This solution appears to work.

Comment: This configuration led to two problems in my project. First, I faced `botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (SlowDown) when calling the DeleteObject operation (reached max retries: 4): Reduce your request rate.` errors after running `collectstatic` command. Second, my CPU started to max out under the normal load. While the botocore error obviously is related to custom ManifestStaticFiles logic, CPU performance peaks are just weird. I used it with `ManifestFilesMixin`

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish this without accessing a private save function? Pylint rightfully complains about the `_save` call since it's been intentionally marked private and likely prone to breakage.

Answer (score 4):

There is Django ticket [#27590](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27590) that addresses this question. The ticket has a pull request that implements a solution, but it has not been reviewed yet.

Comment: This is now available as part of Django 4.0+ https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage